# Dkpg error trying to install Mysql 8 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I am trying to install mysql 8 on an AWS Ubuntu 18.04 instance.

Following the instructions, I did:

```
wget –c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

And the response was:

```
--2019-08-19 16:47:28--  http://xn--c-5gn/
Resolving xn--c-5gn (xn--c-5gn)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--c-5gn’
--2019-08-19 16:47:28--  https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
Resolving dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)... 137.254.60.11
Connecting to dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)|137.254.60.11|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb [following]
--2019-08-19 16:47:28--  https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
Resolving repo.mysql.com (repo.mysql.com)... 104.91.33.12
Connecting to repo.mysql.com (repo.mysql.com)|104.91.33.12|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 35560 (35K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb’

mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb                100%[=========================================================================================================>]  34.73K  --.-KB/s    in 0.007s  

2019-08-19 16:47:28 (4.97 MB/s) - ‘mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb’ saved [35560/35560]

FINISHED --2019-08-19 16:47:28--
Total wall clock time: 0.4s
Downloaded: 1 files, 35K in 0.007s (4.97 MB/s)
```

I then did:

```
sudo dpkg –i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

And the response was:

```
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be careful with copying commands from somewhere.

You have typographic "`–`" (*en dash*, 0xe2 0x80 0x93) in your commands, but you should have plain minus sign "`-`" (*hyphen-minus*, 0x2d).

You need to fix the commands to:

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

If you are following some official guide from respectful source - then tell its author to use correct symbols.

---

If you unsure about the command syntax - see manpages:

1. `man wget` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/wget.1.html)
2. `man dpkg` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

Comment: This solved the problem. I copied from the MySQL official site. Weird